# My query pulls data from the same table which causes the output to display empty cells. How do I eliminate these from my output?

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

Okay, going for a second attempt to explain the situation and the issue I am trying to solve since my first attempt failed miserably.

> **TABLES AND DATA**

**Order**

```
------------------------------------------------------
Ordernumber    Copmany    Address        Order_status
------------------------------------------------------
123456789      ABC        Firstlane 1    Dispatched
```

Here I have the `Order` table with all the relevant ship-to data, order number, status etc.

**Picks**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Ordernumber    SKU      QTY    Carton_id    Pick_id    Pick_status  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
123456789      78963    1      K456789      000123     Packed
123456789      41258    1      K456790      000124     Packed
```

The `Picks` table shows which products have been picked for the order.

The `Carton_id` is assigned during the picking process. The `Pick_id` is a system-generated number. Both are unique.

**MasterID**

```
------------------------
Master_id      Child_id     
------------------------
K456789        000123
K456790        000124

------------------------
Master_id      Child_id     
------------------------
CONS8888       K456789
CONS8888       K456790
```

The `MasterID` table will show different results. The first table is the initial pick. The `Carton_ids` will show up as `Master_ids` and the `Pick_ids` will show up as `Child_ids`.

Now, imagine you ordered 2 products. You want both to arrive in the same box. That's taken care of by the warehouse team when the products are packed into one box and this one box is given it's own unique ID. That's what you see in the second table. We call this a "consolidation ID". But as you can see, there is no separate table for this data; everything remains in the `MasterID` table. The "consolidation ID" is now the `Master_id` and the individual `Carton_ids` are the `Child_ids`.

There is a comment in my first query which explains how I tackle the issue of having this data in the same table.

**Manifest**

```
-----------------------------------------------
Ordernumber     Master_id       Tracking_id     
-----------------------------------------------
123456789       CONS8888        TRACK745852458
```

The `Master_id` (in this case the consolidation ID) will be used to finalize the order and generate a tracking ID for the one box which contains both products.

> **OLD QUERY**

The initial query used a `WHERE` clause but it only works when all the tables are populated.

**Query**

```
select o.ordernumber,
     o.order_status,
     p.sku,
     p.pick_status,
     m.master_id,
     m.child_id,
     ma.tracking_id

from order o,
     picks p, 
     masterid m,
     manifest ma 

where o.ordernumber = p.ordernumber
and o.ordernumber = ma.ordernumber
and m.master_id = ma.master_id
and (m.child_id = p.carton_id or m.child_id = p.pick_id) /*the reason
I do this is because if a customer orders 1 product only, the carton_id 
will be used as the master_id instead of packing the individual carton_ids 
under a consolidation_id*/
and o.ordernumber = 123456789;
```

**Output**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ordernumber  Order_status  SKU    Pick_status   Master_id    Child_id    Tracking_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123456789    Dispatched    78963  Packed        CONS8888     K456789     TRACK745852458    
123456789    Dispatched    41258  Packed        CONS8888     K456790     TRACK745852458
```

> **NEW QUERY**

I re-wrote the query using `left join`, but now I ran into the issue of seeing empty cells. I believe this is because I use the `OR` operator. I know you pointed out I should use the `IN` operator since it would give me better performance. I have done that in this updated query, although the results are the same.

**Query**

```
select o.ordernumber,
     o.order_status,
     p.sku,
     p.pick_status,
     m.master_id,
     m.child_id,
     ma.tracking_id

from order o 
     left join picks p 
        on o.ordernumber = p.ordernumber 
     left join masterid m 
        on m.child_id in (p.carton_id, p.pick_id)
     left join manifest ma 
        on m.master_id = ma.master_id

where o.ordernumber = 123456789;
```

**Output**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ordernumber  Order_status  SKU    Pick_status   Master_id    Child_id    Tracking_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123456789    Dispatched    78963  Packed        CONS8888     K456789     TRACK745852458 
123456789    Dispatched    78963  Packed        K456789      000123         
123456789    Dispatched    41258  Packed        CONS8888     K456790     TRACK745852458
123456789    Dispatched    41258  Packed        K456790      000124
```

> **QUESTION**

How do I use a `left/right/inner join` in the new query and get the same results as the old query? I need the results without the empty cells.

The expected output should be this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ordernumber  Order_status  SKU    Pick_status   Master_id    Child_id    Tracking_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123456789    Dispatched    78963  Packed        CONS8888     K456789     TRACK745852458    
123456789    Dispatched    41258  Packed        CONS8888     K456790     TRACK745852458
```

If an order is shipped using a consoliadtion ID, I need to see only that.

Do I have to use a subquery to solve the issue with the `MasterID` table?

Comment: You probably want `WHERE o.ordernumber = 123456789`. (Instead of `and`.)

Comment: Thanks, corrected

Comment: Your question includes a contradiction. On one hand, you state "I want to see even when the manifest table for instance has no data". Then, you state "I need the results without the empty cells". Well, when the manifest table has no data, the left join surely will return nulls. What is it that you truly want? Add the EXPECTED output

Comment: Please update your question with required output from the data you published. Having tried to answer this I'm not sure I understand what you want.

Comment: Removed the contradicting question and added the expected output. It should basically be the same as the first query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to your query:

1 - no join to masterid based on pick_id (since the details for that are already in the picks table;

2 - add or condition for manifest (can be replaced by in if so desired) - get manifest either based on masterid linked through masterid table to carton_id in picks
or directly based on carton_id;

3 - added coalesce in selection to select master_id from masterid table when it exists or use carton_id if nothing is found in the masterid table;

```
 select o.ordernumber,
     o.order_status,
     p.sku,
     p.pick_status,
     coalesce(m.master_id, p.carton_id) as master_id,
     coalesce(m.child_id, p.pick_id) as child_id,
     ma.tracking_id

from t_order o 
     left join picks p 
        on o.ordernumber = p.ordernumber 
     left join masterid m
        on (m.child_id = p.carton_id)
     left join manifest ma 
        on (m.master_id = ma.master_id) or (ma.master_id = p.carton_id)
where o.ordernumber = 123456789;
```

Comment: Thanks, will try these changes. Let's see what it bring up.

Comment: Question, what does the "t_" do in `from t_order o`

Comment: Your query works. Thanks! Now I just need to go over it a few times to understand what you did. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Pomelo - I consider naming a table after an SQL reserved word a bad idea.  So I took it upon myself to rename the table to t_order.  No particular reason other than my weird preferences.

Comment: That's actually a good habit to have. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The empty cells occur because you have MASTER records without MANIFEST records. This is a natural consequence of the left join syntax: we use outer joins when we want to see results even though not all the join criteria are fulfilled. Where the projection has columns from the left-joined tables those columns will be blank when there are no records to populate them.

So, the question is, what do you want to happen when there are MASTER records without MANIFEST records? One approach would be to populate the affected column with a default value:

```
select o.ordernumber,
     o.order_status,
     p.sku,
     p.pick_status,
     m.master_id,
     m.child_id,
     nvl(ma.tracking_id, 'No manifest') as tracking_id

from order o 
     left join picks p 
        on o.ordernumber = p.ordernumber 
     left join masterid m 
        on m.child_id in (p.carton_id, p.pick_id)
     left join manifest ma 
        on m.master_id = ma.master_id

where o.ordernumber = 123456789;
```

Alternatively you could extend the WHERE clause to exclude the rows without a MANIFEST record:

```
select o.ordernumber,
     o.order_status,
     p.sku,
     p.pick_status,
     m.master_id,
     m.child_id,
     ma.tracking_id

from order o 
     left join picks p 
        on o.ordernumber = p.ordernumber 
     left join masterid m 
        on m.child_id in (p.carton_id, p.pick_id)
     left join manifest ma 
        on m.master_id = ma.master_id

where o.ordernumber = 123456789
and ma.tracking_id is not null;
```

But this solution is basically the same as using inner joins, so probably isn't what you want.

Comment: No exactly what I was looking for. But thanks anyway.